# Tomcat doesn't redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: java, tomcat, administration

i am deploying my app to tomcat VPS server. After i set up SSL, i wanted to set up a redirect from http to https address (because if we trying to connect with http, we can't, but with https we can)

For this task i added my to my `web.xml` this piece of code (from tutorials i found on web):

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

But tomcat doesn't do anything! I can't redirect from http to https, and chrome gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`! How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem myself. I just changed port from 443 to 8443 and it is working just fine.